# one button to play and pause with media recording in kotlin

Tags: java, android-studio, kotlin

I would like to know how I can do it with one button to play and pause my MediaRecorder

My intention is to press the button and start recording and when I press it again it will pause and record.

```
buttonRecordandplaying.setOnClickListener {
  <!--Code to play-->
  grabacion = MediaRecorder()
  grabacion.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC)
  grabacion.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP)
  grabacion.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_NB)
  grabacion.setOutputFile(archivoSalida)
  try {
    grabacion.prepare()
    grabacion.start()

  }catch (e:IOException){

  }
  Toast.makeText(this,"Grabando",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
      
}
    
<-- code on puse-->
grabacion.stop()
grabacion.release()
Toast.makeText(this, "Grabacin finaliza", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add 1 value for checking playing state

```
             private boolean isPlaying = false
```

Then make it true when  the player is playing. And make it false when you stop the player.
Also you can check that value and change the play button icon.

```
         buttonRecordandplaying.setOnClickListener {
            if(!isPlaying) {
               <!--Code to play-->
       
               grabacion = MediaRecorder()
               grabacion.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC)
               grabacion.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP)
               grabacion.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_NB)
               grabacion.setOutputFile(archivoSalida)
               try {
                   grabacion.prepare()
                   grabacion.start()
                   isPlaying = true
                 }catch (e:IOException){

                 }
               Toast.makeText(this,"Grabando",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
               }else {
                <-- code on puse-->
                isPlaying = false
                grabacion.stop()
                grabacion.release()
                Toast.makeText(this, "Grabacin finaliza", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
             }
```